# Why does Relation.size sometimes return a Hash in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, arel

I can run a query in two different ways to return a Relation.

When I interrogate the size of the Relation one query gives a Fixnum as expected the other gives a Hash which is a hash of each value in the Relations Group By statement with the number of occurrences of each.

In Rails 3 I assume it always returned a Fixnum as I never had a problem whereeas with Rails 4 it sometimes returns a Hash and a statement like Rel.size.zero?  gives the error:

> undefined method `zero?' for {}:Hash

Am I best just using the .blank? method to check for zero records to be sure of avoiding unexpected errors?

Here is a snippet of code with looging statements for the two queries and the resulting log

CODE:

```
assessment_responses1=AssessmentResponse.select("process").where("client_id=? and final = ?",self.id,false).group("process")
logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------")
logger.info("assessment_responses1.class = #{assessment_responses1.class}")
logger.info("assessment_responses1.size.class = #{assessment_responses1.size.class}")
logger.info("assessment_responses1.size value = #{assessment_responses1.size}")

logger.info("............................................................")

assessment_responses2=AssessmentResponse.select("distinct process").where("client_id=? and final = ?",self.id,false)
logger.info("assessment_responses2.class = #{assessment_responses2.class}")
logger.info("assessment_responses2.size.class = #{assessment_responses2.size.class}")
logger.info("assessment_responses2.size values = #{assessment_responses2.size}")
logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------")
```

LOG

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
assessment_responses1.class = ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_AssessmentResponse
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(`assessment_responses`.`process`) AS count_process, process AS process FROM `assessment_responses` WHERE `assessment_responses`.`organisation_id` = 17 AND (client_id=43932 and final = 0) GROUP BY process
assessment_responses1.size.class = Hash
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(`assessment_responses`.`process`) AS count_process, process AS process FROM `assessment_responses` WHERE `assessment_responses`.`organisation_id` = 17 AND (client_id=43932 and final = 0) GROUP BY process
assessment_responses1.size value = {"6 Month Review(1)"=>3, "Assessment(1)"=>28, "Assessment(2)"=>28}
............................................................
assessment_responses2.class = ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_AssessmentResponse
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(distinct process) FROM `assessment_responses` WHERE `assessment_responses`.`organisation_id` = 17 AND (client_id=43932 and final = 0)
assessment_responses2.size.class = Fixnum
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(distinct process) FROM `assessment_responses` WHERE `assessment_responses`.`organisation_id` = 17 AND (client_id=43932 and final = 0)
assessment_responses2.size values = 3
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`size` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object translates to `count`, because the former tries to get the count of the `Relation`. But when you call `count` on a grouped `Relation` object, you receive a hash.

The keys of this hash are the grouped column's values; the values of this hash are the respective counts.

```
AssessmentResponse.group(:client_id).count # this will return a Hash
AssessmentResponse.group(:client_id).size # this will also return a Hash
```

This is true for the [following methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html): `count`, `sum`, `average`, `maximum`, and `minimum`.

If you want to check for rows being present or not, simply use `exists?` i.e. do the following:

```
AssessmentResponse.group(:client_id).exists?
```

Instead of this:

```
AssessmentResponse.group(:client_id).count.zero?
```

Comment: You are undoubtedly right Humza. What seems puzzling is that it must have changed for Rail 4 as my code has been working by checking 'size.zero?' for years on Rails 1 2 and 3.

Comment: And for those who came here needing to get the actual number of records, use `.length` instead of `.size`.